# Firebase Database Rules - Permission Denied

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm creating a Group Chat app and I already created the [rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpyWZ.png)

However, I got permission denied when I'm trying to read the group from my Android device. The reference in my Android Project: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJi4O.png)

The class which stores the data of the group is something like:
(general information about the group like when it was created etc.) And it also stores information about the members of the group in a Map, where the key is the UID and the value is the Member. Member is another object with information about the member. So, like this: 
- created
- updated
- lastMessage
- Map <'String, Member> members 
Unfortunately, I don't know what mistakes I did.

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of text. Instead replace the pictures with the actual text, which you can copy page from your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/).

Answer (score 0):

I know what was the problem. The rule is in its child element, so Firebase give me always permission deny when I want to access to the message_groups.